# replace two character: apostrophe and space in PHP

Tags: php, regex, str-replace

How can I remove two character? Here's my code:

```
str_replace('\'| ', '',"remove ' and spaces");
```

I'm trying to use the | but it's not working

Comment: `echo str_replace("' ", "","remove ' and spaces");`

Comment: What is exactly your desired output?

Comment: `str_replace()` doesn't take regular expression, take a look at `preg_replace()`

Comment: `str_replace(array("'", " "), "", $string);`

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. I got it now using preg_replace. @Rizier123

Answer (score 2):

Looking at `\'|`, it seems you want to remove either `'` or a space. [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) (that does not allow regex as its *needle* argument) accepts an *array* of search strings as the first argument:

> `search`
>   The value being searched for, otherwise known as the needle. **An array may be used to designate multiple needles.**

So, use

```
$s = str_replace(array("'",' '), "", "remove ' and spaces");
// => removeandspaces
```

See [demo](https://ideone.com/umw0zd)